# How Can I Increase Maximum Nesting Level?

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compiling, newlib

I want to make an operating system for the Raspberry Pi, and I need a cross-compiler. I decided to build it on Mac OS X and I'm using the GNU compiler toolchain and the 'arm-none-eabi' target.

After building binutils and installing some other dependencies I began building the cross-compiler. I'm using GCC version 6.2.0, and when I run 'make all-gcc', the process fails and returns the following error.

```
../../gcc-6.2.0/gcc/config/arm/thumb1.md:1615:10873: fatal error: bracket nesting level exceeded maximum of 256
../../gcc-6.2.0/gcc/config/arm/thumb1.md:1615:10873: note: use -fbracket-depth=N to increase maximum nesting level
15 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [insn-attrtab.o] Error 1
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

However, I don't understand what it means by telling me to set a higher bracket nesting level using fbracket-depth.

Where do I put this fbracket-depth, and how high should I set it?

Comment: That's weird. gcc itself doesn't seem to have a `-fbracket-depth` option, and I can't find any other tool that has such an option. If it did, I'd suggest that the real problem is that nothing should have that many nested brackets. `thumb1.md` is a "Machine Description" file, but I see nothing odd on line 1615. 10873 should be a column number, but there are no lines nearly that long. Could your `thumb1.md` file be corrupted?

Comment: @KeithThompson Both GCC 6.1 and 5.4 give the same error, but 5.4 says it's in the neon.md file. This is so odd!

Comment: Did you take a look at the `thumb1.md` file? In gcc-6.2.0, it should be 56948 bytes, 1812 lines, with the longest line 93 characters long.

Comment: I checked it. It makes no sense. I'm doing this for my employer, but I've done it several times at home. This only happens with this target. @KeithThompson

Comment: You checked it -- and you found what, exactly? And can you provide a bit more context for the error message (a few lines leading up to it)?

Comment: Searching for that error message turns up quite a few hits, all seemingly people building GCC on Macs, and from a couple of minutes of reading appears to be something to do with the system "gcc" actually being Clang.